# Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000 after calling Isolate::New()

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I can't seem to figure out something getting V8 started up.  I have this code:

```
if (!_V8Initialized)
{
    v8::V8::InitializeICU();

    v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData("x86\\"); // (this loads ok, I checked)

    auto platform = v8::platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform);

    v8::V8::Initialize();

    _V8Initialized = true;
}

auto params = Isolate::CreateParams();
params.array_buffer_allocator = ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
_Isolate = Isolate::New(params);
```

But I get this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in V8.Net.Console.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.
>
> v8_libbase.dll!v8::base::OS::Abort() Line 832   C++
>       v8_libbase.dll!V8_Fatal(const char * file, int line, const char * format, ...) Line 74  C++
>       v8.dll!v8::internal::SnapshotData::SnapshotData(const v8::internal::Vector snapshot) Line 28  C++
>       v8.dll!v8::internal::Snapshot::Initialize(v8::internal::Isolate * isolate) Line 43  C++
>       v8.dll!v8::Isolate::New(const v8::Isolate::CreateParams & params) Line 8237 C++
>       V8_Net_Proxy_x64.dll!V8EngineProxy::V8EngineProxy(bool enableDebugging, void(*)() debugMessageDispatcher, int debugPort) Line 89    C++
>       V8_Net_Proxy_x64.dll!CreateV8EngineProxy(bool enableDebugging, void(*)() debugMessageDispatcher, int debugPort) Line 19 C++
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       V8.Net.dll!V8.Net.V8Engine.V8Engine() Line 246  C#
>       V8.Net.Console.exe!V8.Net.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 31   C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       mscoreei.dll!00007ffdbdd281ad() Unknown
>       mscoree.dll!00007ffdbddc10ab()  Unknown
>       kernel32.dll!00007ffdd3868364() Unknown
>       ntdll.dll!00007ffdd5ef70d1()    Unknown

It seems to be failing here:

```
explicit SnapshotData(const Vector<const byte> snapshot)
  : SerializedData(const_cast<byte*>(snapshot.begin()), snapshot.length()) {
    CHECK(IsSane()); <-- THIS FAILS
}
```

I followed the source code here (for the most part): https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/4.8/samples/hello-world.cc

... but I'm not sure why it seems I'm getting a null error. I must be missing something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, I always seem to figure things out AFTER posting to SO, lol. It turns out I was loading from the x86 directory and not the x64 directory (which I should have guess given the V8_Net_Proxy_x64.dll! lol).

I was going to delete the question, but I'll leave this here anyhow in case someone else falls into this in the middle of the night half asleep. ;)

Comment: how did you got this exception and dll info pasted in error section. facing the same issue but not getting such detailed trace. i am using visual studio 22

Comment: You have to build the V8.Net libraries with debug info, and make sure those are the ones your are loading when in debug mode in VS.