# OpenCV DirectX 11 Interoperability

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, directx, directx-11

I need to read an image in OpenCV, send it to DirectX, do some processing, and then send the output image back to OpenCV. I am completely new to this, and was working with DirectX 11, therefore, I decided to refer [this sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/directx/d3d11_interop.cpp) which demonstrates OpenCV and DirectX interoperability. There are options for both GPU and CPU modes, but right now, I plan to use only the CPU. The program builds without any errors, but returns the following runtime error everytime:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in Direct3D Win32 my_project_name.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000. occurred
```

I looked for solutions everywhere but couldn't find any. Since this is a sample, I guess many people might have used this. 
Here are the lines where I'm getting an exception.

```
if (cv::ocl::haveOpenCL())
        {
            m_oclCtx = cv::directx::ocl::initializeContextFromD3D11Device(m_pD3D11Dev); //this is the line which throws the exception
        }

        m_oclDevName = cv::ocl::useOpenCL() ?
            cv::ocl::Context::getDefault().device(0).name() :
            "No OpenCL device";
```

On hovering the cursor above `m_pD3D11Dev`, this message is displayed by the intellisense:

```
m_pD3D11Dev | 0x000001f5a286c618 <No type information available in symbol file for d3d11.dll>
```

I am guessing that there is some error in my setup or some other linker error since this is a sample code provided by OpenCV(which i am assuming is obviously going to run). Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

I'm using DirectX 11 and OpenCV 3.4.4 to build(x64) this in Visual Studio 19. I also tried building(x64) it in Visual Studio 17, but the results were same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215911/access-violation-executing-location-0x0000000000000000-after-calling-isolatene)?

Comment: Hey @YunusTemurlenk, thanks for the comment. I went through the post, re-checked my code and am sure I have not made such a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out though.